# Server accessible from laptop, but not iPad or Android phone

Tags: networking, server, ssh, android

I hope someone can help, I'm not sure on preferred formatting, so I hope this is good.

- OS: Ubuntu 18.04 server
- Hardware: Intel NUC i3, Intel 7260 wifi,  plume WiFi

Problem:
Recently moved the server to a Wi-Fi connection for better placement at home.
When connected to Wi-Fi, I can see the server is connected in the plume app, but I cannot access it from all devices.

Sometimes it is the iPad, sometimes the laptop.

What's stranger that the server is not even visible to the device, it does not respond to ping, it does not load any webpage it serves. It's like it's non-existent.

Doing a scan of the network and I can see every other device. I double-checked and I can see every single other device that is connected to Wi-Fi, just not the server.

I am going mad, as it is a weird question that is hard to google.

I have restarted all network equipment and the server.
The firewall is disabled for now also.

Comment: As an update for plume routers specifically. The issue seemed to come from using the same server as a DNS server for plume router. Perhaps having an IP it assigns as its own DNS causes a problem. I had to use another service to get DNS as blocking, but will try pointing it to the external URL and forward the ports.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the title of your question is: "did you realize that Android does NOT respect the DHCP supplied value for the DNS"? In other words, Android uses the Google 8.8.8.8 DNS, regardless of what your access point (Plume?) tells it to use. 8.8.8.8 does not know the addresses of your internal IPs.

Comment: Whilst that wouldn't surprise me, I don't think it is correct.  I have used PiHole with my android device successfully before I moved it to WiFi. I also noticed it blocks adds in app as well as web pages. Secondly, I can (and have now) used another external DNS service to block adds successfully on my android device. Third, it also seemed to affect my iPad.